# I am new to oop and had follwed my teacher and youtube but still seem stuck and get errors

Tags: python

I seem to get the error

```
    Bucky = Child("red","black")
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

however , I followed my teacher , I need some assitance and was hoping to inherit the attributes from MOTHER  and  Father

```
class Mother :
    def __init__(self, eyeColor):
        self._eyeColor = eyeColor

class Father :
    def __init__(self, hairColor):
        self._hairColor = hairColor
class Child(Mother,Father):
    def __init__(self, eyeColor):
        Mother.__init__(self,eyeColor)
    def __init__(self, hairColor):
        Father.__init__(self,hairColor)


Bucky = Child("red","black")
print(Bucky._hairColor)
print(Bucky._eyeColor)
```

Comment: Why did you define 2 separate `__init__` methods in `Child`?

Comment: The actual inheritance you've created isn't a great example in terms of programming, its suggesting that the child itself is both a mother and father which whilst it might grow up to play both roles, its probably not what you intended.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. What's your question exactly? You probably want to know why the error is happening and how to fix it, right? Please [edit] to clarify, and write a more descriptive title while you're there, like "How do I set attributes from both parents in `__init__()`?". It'd also help to add your desired output, which I imagine is `red` then `black`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, ignoring that this isn't how genetics work, you have made several issues here.

1. `Child` should not subclass `Mother` or `Father`. Even though it might make sense, if `A` is a subclass of `B`, that means every `A` is a `B`. So, every `Cat` is an `Animal`. Every `Ferrari` is a `Car`. Is every `Child` a `Mother` and a `Father`? (...)
2. You defined `__init__` twice. Perhaps you meant to do `__init__(self, eyeColor, hairColor)`.
3. Only the last definition of `__init__` will matter. `Child("red", "black")` provides two arguments to the constructor (which is three positional arguments, because of the `self`), and since your `Child`'s constructor only has two arguments, this will error.

I think what you want to do is make `Person` a class and then do this:

```py
class Person:
    def __init__(self, mother, father):
        self.mother = mother
        self.father = father
        self.hairColor = father.hairColor # this is not how genetics works
        self.eyeColor = mother.eyeColor # this is not how genetics works
```

This makes a lot more sense because children should know who their parents are but having children and familial relationships should be properties, not part of the class itself. In true OOP, you could make `Mother` an interface and have instances include that if they are a mother.

Comment: For some background, this is called [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming#Composition,_inheritance,_and_delegation).

Answer (score 0):

The example itself its not really good, but if you must, this will do.

```
class Mother :
    def __init__(self, eyeColor, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._eyeColor = eyeColor

class Father :
    def __init__(self, hairColor, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._hairColor = hairColor

class Child(Mother,Father):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


Bucky = Child(eyeColor="red",hairColor="black")
print(Bucky._hairColor)
print(Bucky._eyeColor)
```